# How to display total number of records using smart table in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, pagination, smart-table

I am using smart-table for displaying the records.
Using custom pagination to display the records 20 per page.

I want to display pagination like :  1 - 20 of 25 Records
How can I accomplish this ? 
- I tried using (num of pages * total pages), but this will round the result.

Comment: Link to code - http://plnkr.co/edit/zk6PLwJIaaQysGAyXHic

Comment: Could you post your code in your question please otherwise this question becomes useless to anyone else if your link goes dead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `totalItemCount` which is present inside `tableState.pagination`.
Just populate that value once you get data from server and use that value in the pagination template.

Comment: Thankyou! Thats what I needed. I can set total record count to tableState.pagination.totalItemCount and can access that in my pagination html like {{totalItemCount}}.            Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by dhiraj tiwari answer, watch wouldn't work unless wrapped in function call:

```
  .directive('stPaginationSummary', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^stTable',
      template: '<span>Showing <strong>{{from}}</strong>-<strong>{{to}}</strong> of <strong>{{total}}</strong> Record(s)</span>',
      scope: {},
      link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        var listener = function () {
          var pagination = ctrl.tableState().pagination
          scope.from = pagination.totalItemCount === 0 ? 0 : pagination.start + 1
          scope.to = Math.min(pagination.start + pagination.number, pagination.totalItemCount)
          scope.total = pagination.totalItemCount
        }
        scope.$watch(function () {
          return ctrl.tableState()
        }, listener, true)
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution to my problem. I know this is an old issue but to make it more helpfull for others, I wanted to show how to make this solution even better.

The answer you gave is correct on the first page and following pages but not always on the last one.

You do it like this:

```
<span class="pagination-info itemCount">
     {{(currentPage-1)*stItemsByPage+1}}-
     {{currentPage*stItemsByPage}} 
     of {{numPages*stItemsByPage}} Records
</span>
```

If the number of records on the last page is less than stItemsByPage it will never be correct.  This would be better in that case:

```
<span class="pagination-info itemCount">
     {{(currentPage-1)*stItemsByPage+1}}-
     {{(currentPage*stItemsByPage) > totalItemCount?totalItemCount:(currentPage*stItemsByPage)}} 
     of {{numPages*stItemsByPage}} Records
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your should create Directive

```
ticketsApp.directive('stSummary', function () {

    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^stTable',
    template:'<span><b>[[pagination.start ]]  of [[pagination.totalItemCount]] items</b></span>',
    scope: {},
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
      var listener = function (val) {
        scope.pagination = ctrl.tableState().pagination;
        scope.to = Math.min(scope.pagination.start + scope.pagination.number, scope.total || 0);
      };
      scope.$watch(ctrl.tableState(), listener, true);
    }
  }
});`
```

After that you should use "stSummary"  Tag in your view.
Ex :

```
<st-summary st-items-by-page="10" 
            class="pull-right"
            class="pagination-info itemCountnumber">
</st-summary>`
```